# Error en rutas de laravel

Tags: laravel-5, php7

Estoy creando un sitio de laravel multi-idioma, necesito crear dos grupos de rutas que me permitan procesar peticiones como midominio.com/idioma o midominio.com/pais/idioma, para ello en el archivo web.php (de rutas) agregué los siguientes:

```
$myroutes =  function () {
    Auth::routes();
};

Route::group(['prefix' => '{country}/{language}', 'where' => ['language' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}','country' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], $myroutes);

Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}', 'where' => ['language' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], $myroutes);
```

El problema que tengo es que cada vez que pido o hago una redirección como esta:

```
route('login',[$request->language, $request->country]);
```

Me va a la ruta:

midominio.com/idioma/login?pais

Es decir, siempre cae en el grupo:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}', 'where' => ['language' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], $myroutes);
```

¿Alguien sabe que pueda ser ?

Comment: Hola Manuel, intenta cambiando tu codigo de ```route('login',[$request->language, $request->country]);``` por el siguiente ```route('login',[$request->country, $request->language]);``` . Como notaras, primero coloca el country y luego el language, ya que asi lo definiste en tus rutas.

Comment: Hola, ya lo he corregido pero sigue haciendo lo mismo, no me toma el segundo bloque de ruta {country}/{language} a pesar de pasarle los dos parámetros de ruta.